# React Native Search Filter SectionList

Tags: react-native, search

I want to create a search filter for my `SectionList` but I can't seem to be able to do it. I created a `SectionList` which shows the clusters with different data. I want to search like `sweet` or `fun` from cluster2 but it doesn't work. Below is my code. Would appreciate it if someone can help me or provide an alternate solution to search.

This is my Clusters component

```
const KEYS_TO_FILTERS = ['data'];
import {ClusterData} from '../data/ClusterData';

export default class Cluster1 extends Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchTerm: ''
    }
  }
  searchUpdated(term) {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: term })
  }
render(){
    const filteredMoods = ClusterData.filter(createFilter(this.state.searchTerm, KEYS_TO_FILTERS))
 return(
     <View style={styles.container}>
    <SearchInput 
      onChangeText={(term) => { this.searchUpdated(term) }} 
      style={styles.searchInput}
      placeholder="Type a mood to search"
      />
         <SectionList  

          renderItem={({item,index})=>{
              return(
             <SectionListItem  item={item} index={index}> </SectionListItem>);}} 
                       sections={ClusterData}
                       keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name}>
         </SectionList>
     </View>      
 );
 }}    
 class SectionListItem extends Component{
 render(){
     return(
         <View>
         <Text style={styles.moodname}>{this.props.item.name}</Text>
         </View>
     );
 }
 }
```

This is my data component

```
const ClusterData = [
{ title: 'Cluster1', 
data: 
[
  {name: 'passionate'},
  {name: 'rousing'},
  {name: 'confident'},
  {name: 'boisterous'},
  {name: 'rowdy'}
],
},
{ title: 'Cluster2', 
  data: 
[
  {name: 'rollicking'},
  {name: 'cheerful'},
  {name: 'fun'},
  {name: 'sweet'},
  {name: 'amiable'},
  {name: 'natured'}
],
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can put your sections data in the state and then you can change it dynamicly, just add to your Cluster1 state dataToShow state and the initial data will be the ClusterData. Then you need to change in the sectionList sections data to `sections={this.state.dataToShow}`

And

On your search input function you can add the follow:

```
searchUpdated(term) {
let matchedItemsArr = [];
//Run a loop to check if the input value match the title.
for(let i = 0; i < this.state.dataToShow.length; i++){
  if(this.state.dataToShow[i].title.includes(term)){
    matchedItemsArr.push(this.state.dataToShow[i]);
  }
 }
 //If the input is empty set the data back to its origin data
 if(term === ''){
    this.setState({ dataToShow: ClusterData, searchTerm: term });
  }else{
 this.setState({ dataToShow: matchedItemsArr, searchTerm: term });
 }
}
```

Comment: There's an error at this line matchedItemsArr.push({ this.state.dataToShow[i] }); it say that ':' is expected.

Comment: fixed my answer.

Comment: I tried to add in the search input function and changing my sections={this.stat.dataToShow} but my object is undefined. I put up a screenshot of the output

Comment: forgot an e in the `sections={this.state.dataToShow}`

Answer (score -1):

Simply follow these steps for making search filter function.

suppose we have an array of objects like.

```
this.state = {
ClusterData : [
    { title: 'Cluster1', 
    data: 
    [
      {name: 'passionate'},
      {name: 'rousing'},
      {name: 'confident'},
      {name: 'boisterous'},
      {name: 'rowdy'}
    ],
    },
    { title: 'Cluster2', 
      data: 
    [
      {name: 'rollicking'},
      {name: 'cheerful'},
      {name: 'fun'},
      {name: 'sweet'},
      {name: 'amiable'},
      {name: 'natured'}
    ]}

filterArray = (text) => {
        let search = text.toLowerCase();
        this.setState({
            check: this.state.ClusterData.filter(obj => obj.name.toLowerCase().includes(search))
        });
    }
```

and call this function on inputText like

```
<TextInput onChangeText={(val) => { this.filterArray(val) }} placeholder={'Search'}/>
```